# Package requires NuGet client version ... or above

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

After I download my project from GitHub and try to compile it I am running into the issue of "package requires NuGet client version ... or above" but I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the latest NuGet version for that version. The issue is fixed after building the package twice but is there a way that I could stop this from happening in the first place and have it so that these issues go away after the first compilation of the code?

Comment: I haven't seen this error message in years, but it used to say "requires version X, current version is Y" or something to that effect. What are the version numbers in the error message? Around here it's generally expected that you'll provide the exact error message in this type of question.

Comment: NuGet Client 2.12 version is required in order to get Newtonsoft.Json 11.0.1. currently the NuGet version is 2.8.60717.93. - That is the error.

Comment: Do you have a setup that includes a nuget.exe and a targets file as part of the repository? That was used as a "restore on build" feature before NuGet was fully integrated into VS

Comment: Yeah, it has those files. How would I convert it over or something?

Comment: https://www.xavierdecoster.com/post/2014/03/06/migrate-away-from-msbuild-based-nuget-package-restore.html Most developers have done the migration years ago, so you can follow the examples.

Comment: Please read that post one more time, as it carefully talked about build server case, and you should not upload your `packages` folder in all cases. Besides, with VS 2017, you should even upgrade another time to package references, instead of `packages.config`. Google that and learn it through.

Comment: Visual Studio 2017 cannot contain a version lower than 4.x. 
2.x versions of NuGet do not ship/install/work with VS 2017 in any way. 

Can you clarifiy what do you mean by "currently the NuGet version is 2.8.60717.93"?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was talking to some C# Developers over discord and the original project was created all the way back in 2013. They advised me to update the code for 2017 and change the .NET target framework, so that was how I resolved the issue in the end. I believe it had something to do with the nuget.exe that was contained within the projects .nuget folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem while adding NUnit via Nugget Manager. Instead of adding the package via Nuget Manager, I downloaded the framework's dll files from their website and add them as a reference to the project.

If you still want to use the NuGet manager, you have to upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio